# override merge two branches in Git

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Is there any way to merge branch A into B and Override anything in B with what with A no matter if there are conflicts or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  the `-X` flag to specify which to prefer, `ours` or `theirs`.

`git merge <branch> -X ours` will always prefer the version of the branch you are currently on, whereas `git merge <branch> -X theirs` will prefer the version of the branch being merged.

Checkout the following from `man git-merge` for more details:

> **ours**
>
> This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring our version. Changes from the other tree that do not conflict with our side are reflected to the merge result. For a binary file, the entire contents are taken from our side.
>
> **theirs**
>
> This is the opposite of "ours".

So in your case, running `git merge B -X ours` when on branch `A` should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

The two answers already posted (`-X ours` and `-s ours`) are both correct, or, equivalently, both wrong.  It depends on what you want as a result.

Here's a simple but concrete example.  Suppose we have the following:

```
          O
        /   \
... - B       M
        \   /
          T
```

where `B` is the common base commit, `O` is "our" commit, `T` is "their" commit, and `M` is the merged result (that we want generated).

Suppose further that in commit `B`, file `conflict.txt` says:

```
I am a file
that contains
some text.
```

Another file, `README`, is completely empty.

In commit `O`, we changed line two to read `that has` instead of `that contains`.  (That is, we changed line two a bit.)  We did not touch `README` at all.

In commit `T`, they changed line two to read `that used to have`.`(That is, they changed the word "contains" to "still contains".)  They also added some text to`README`.

Now, if you ask git to merge their branch into our branch, there will be a conflict in file `conflict.txt`, because git doesn't know what to do with the conflicting changes.  Using `-X ours` tells git: in case of conflict, use our version, so commit `M` will keep our change and discard their change.

On the other hand, there is *no* conflict with `README`, because we did not change it.  Only *they* changed `README`.  With `-X ours`, commit `M` will keep their change.

Using `-s ours`, however, git will keep our version of `README` as well.

It's not clear to me, based on your question, which of these—or perhaps what third non-built-in alternative—you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$ git checkout branchA
$ git merge -s ours branchB
```

This merging is called the "ours" merging strategy.

Check out more on the merging documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).